# Docker exec linux terminal create alias

Tags: bash, docker, terminal, exec, alias

I have a running and detached container. I want to create a command alias there before attaching to that container.

When I am attached to the container and I type:

```
alias bar='foo'
```

an alias is created, and might be checked by:

```
alias
```

command.

but if I want to do the same by **docker exec** command ie this way

```
docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash -c "alias bar='foo'"
```

it does not work, probably because when I'm attached to the container and type into its terminal

```
/bin/bash -c "alias bar='foo'"
```

it does not work as well.

Do you know how to modify `alias bar='foo'` so it works together with `docker exec` command applied to a detached container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `alias` built-in creates an alias in the current shell. Aliases, like environment variables, are not persisted, only loaded. You need to update your .bashrc or whatever inside the container to have the desired alias so that it can be loaded on each start of bash.

Answer (score 9):

Alias in your bashrc file does not directly accept parameters. Although in your case you will have to create a function and alias that.

You can add following on your ~/.bashrc

```sh
dexec() {
    docker exec -it "$1" /bin/bash
    echo "$1"
}
```

you can also use `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`

and don't forget to do

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

ideally, you can do something like this

```
dexec <container_id/container_name>
```

Answer (score 2):

add into your Dockerfile something like
`RUN echo alias bar='foo' >> ~/.bashrc`
Actually, if you running your container under a user other than `root` you need to put this command into the correct `.bashrc`