# how to inject aliases when execute docker exec?

Tags: bash, docker, exec, aliases

I want to inject a few alias when execute docker exec command, otherwise I need to type such as alias ll='ls -l' everytime, so I made this a piece of code, but finally no aliases at all, anybody can help fixed this problem?

```
    $ docker exec -itu root $(docker ps -l -q) bash -c "echo alias ll=\'ls -laF\' >> /alias.sh; \
           shopt -s expand_aliases; source /alias.sh; exec bash"

    root@c9ed5e18f77d:/# ll
    bash: ll: command not found
    root@c9ed5e18f77d:/# alias
    root@c9ed5e18f77d:/# source /alias.sh
    root@c9ed5e18f77d:/# alias
    alias ll='ls -laF'
```

I have also tried this, it doesn't work either.

```
    $ docker exec -itu root $(docker ps -l -q) bash -c "alias ll='ls -laF'; shopt -s expand_aliases; exec bash"
```

The docker container is debian-based, I can run this no problem, so I thought this is a trick about bash, please help.

```
    $ docker exec -itu root $(docker ps -l -q) bash -c 'cd /opt; exec bash'
    root@c9ed5e18f77d:/opt# pwd
    /opt
    root@c9ed5e18f77d:/opt#
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker exec linux terminal create alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297615/docker-exec-linux-terminal-create-alias)

Comment: You can't judge by the subject, I provided the code ask people for help, not ask the concept, [ Docker exec linux terminal create alias ] doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Aliases aren't inherited by the shell you start with `exec bash`. Just put them in the appropriate initialization file sourced by `bash` when it starts.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use named pipe

E.x. `docker compose exec -it radarr bash -c "exec bash --init-file <(echo alias 'll=ls\\ -la')"`

```bash
user@pc:~$ docker compose exec -it radarr bash -c "exec bash --init-file <(echo alias 'll=ls\\ -la')"
b2b0b66b8ff1:/# ll
total 176
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 Oct 10 12:22 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 Oct 10 12:22 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root      0 Oct 10 12:22 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x   1 abc  users  4096 Oct  1 19:59 app
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  12288 Sep 30 16:29 command
drwxr-xr-x   4 abc  users    12 Oct 10 13:54 config
drwxr-xr-x   1 abc  users  4096 Sep 30 16:29 defaults
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root    320 Oct 10 12:22 dev
-rwxr--r--   1 root root  18909 Jan  1  1970 docker-mods
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     42 Oct  1 19:59 donate.txt
drwxrwsr-x   5 abc  users     5 Oct 10 07:33 downloads
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 Oct 10 12:22 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 home
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    907 May  5 02:55 init
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 lsiopy
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 Oct 10 12:22 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 opt
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 package
dr-xr-xr-x 485 root root      0 Oct 10 12:22 proc
drwx------   1 root root   4096 Oct 10 13:14 root
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 Oct 10 12:22 run
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root      0 Oct 10 12:22 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root   4096 Oct 10 12:22 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 usr
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root   4096 Sep 30 16:29 var
b2b0b66b8ff1:/#
```